# ngOnChanges fires nonstop and makes application not to repond

Tags: angular, ngonchanges, lifecycle-hook

I built a component with the name of "gw-responsive-tabs" that has an input with variable (navLinks) which is an Array of the tabs I want to display. When I deliver the input data from the html like that:

```
<gw-responsive-tabs
  [navLinks]="[{ label: 'PENDING', path: '/mentoring/manage/pending' },
  { label: 'CURRENT', path: '/mentoring/manage/pending' }]">
</gw-responsive-tabs>
```

Then everything works as expected and I can see 2 tabs.

If I change it and send the same Data using a getter or a function than the ngOnChanges of the gw-responsive-tabs component fires nonstop with very high frequency and from that point the chrome is not responding.

```
get mentoringTabs(): Array<any> {
  return [{ label: 'PENDING', path: '/mentoring/manage/pending' }, { label: 'CURRENT', path: '/mentoring/manage/pending' }];
}
```

and the html:

```
<gw-responsive-tabs [navLinks]="mentoringTabs"></gw-responsive-tabs>
```

Any ideas what can cause this phenomena?

Comment: The getter has to be called in every change detection cycle and since you return a new object everytime, Angular treats this as changed data and fires OnChange.

Comment: How do you know that is the cause of application fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the change detection default strategy it's checked every sec or so And no matter what if the value of the return object is changed or not it re-render the template and because of that every time it's re rendering the html it's calling the get method which returns a new object everytime it's called and when the ngOnChanges compares it as the value is a new object now it runs in a loop.

here is the link to how change detection works 
https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/change-detection/angular_1_vs_angular_2.html

Comment: I changed the changeDetection stategy to onPush and still with no success. Beside that - change detection will occure whether you send the data using a function or an hardcoded data in the HTML.

Comment: can you please add the html for the gw-responsive-tabs because I tried what you are trying to do https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y7p4zw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts and it only throws ngChange twice which is what it should do